# Unable to login with Xorg 17.10 using Gnome/Xorg combo

Tags: gnome, xorg, login, 17.10

Due to my nvidia GPU and my favourite terminal not currently supporting Wayland I need to use Xorg as the server.

During login, selecting the gear relating to GNOME with Xorg (after installing 17.10 I switched to the vanilla GNOME interface) gives me a black flashing screen and I am then ejected back to the login screen. Can anyone provied some insight as to what I need to do to resolve this?

I am able to login through openbox and `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` gives me x11 so I know Xorg is present. 
I have run the Ubuntu repair utility that comes with the installer.

I have set `WaylandEnable=false` in  `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` to false and that lets the login screen run Xorg however the flashing black screen issue persists.

This is my last  faile login from `/var/log/auth.log` using ubuntu gnome:

```
Dec  5 18:37:37 micks-MS-7A33 gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user micks by micks(uid=0)
Dec  5 18:37:37 micks-MS-7A33 systemd-logind[886]: New session 6 of user micks.
Dec  5 18:37:37 micks-MS-7A33 dbus[869]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="error", sender=":1.2" (uid=0 pid=886 comm="/lib/systemd/systemd-logind ") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod" requested_reply="0" d
estination=":1.177" (uid=1000 pid=2861 comm="/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/use")
Dec  5 18:37:38 micks-MS-7A33 dbus[869]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="error", sender=":1.2" (uid=0 pid=886 comm="/lib/systemd/systemd-logind ") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod" requested_reply="0" d
estination=":1.177" (uid=1000 pid=2861 comm="/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/use")
Dec  5 18:37:38 micks-MS-7A33 dbus[869]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="error", sender=":1.2" (uid=0 pid=886 comm="/lib/systemd/systemd-logind ") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod" requested_reply="0" d
estination=":1.177" (uid=1000 pid=2861 comm="/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/use")
Dec  5 18:37:38 micks-MS-7A33 dbus[869]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="error", sender=":1.2" (uid=0 pid=886 comm="/lib/systemd/systemd-logind ") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod" requested_reply="0" d
estination=":1.177" (uid=1000 pid=2861 comm="/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/use")
Dec  5 18:37:38 micks-MS-7A33 dbus[869]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="error", sender=":1.2" (uid=0 pid=886 comm="/lib/systemd/systemd-logind ") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod" requested_reply="0" d
estination=":1.177" (uid=1000 pid=2861 comm="/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/use")
Dec  5 18:37:38 micks-MS-7A33 dbus[869]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="error", sender=":1.2" (uid=0 pid=886 comm="/lib/systemd/systemd-logind ") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod" requested_reply="0" d
estination=":1.177" (uid=1000 pid=2861 comm="/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/use")
Dec  5 18:37:38 micks-MS-7A33 dbus[869]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="error", sender=":1.2" (uid=0 pid=886 comm="/lib/systemd/systemd-logind ") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod" requested_reply="0" d
estination=":1.177" (uid=1000 pid=2861 comm="/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/use")
```

edit:     putting `WaylandEnable=false` back as a comment block still gets me

```
Dec  5 19:13:48 micks-MS-7A33 dbus[877]: message repeated 17 times: [ [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="error", 
sender=":1.0" (uid=0 pid=833 comm="/lib/systemd/systemd-logind ") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="org.freedesktop.DBus
.Error.UnknownMethod" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.147" (uid=1000 pid=4369 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell ")]
```

so `org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod` is still the issue

Answer (score 0):

Setting WaylandEnable to false isn't required to run a session on X.org. I would suggest commenting that line in your config, rebooting, and trying to log into GNOME on Xorg again.

edit: I should add that changing this setting in my own gdm3 config resulted in a similar login issue and reverting the changes I made resolved it.

Comment: commemnting that back out and restarting still gets me


    `Dec  5 19:13:48 micks-MS-7A33 dbus[877]: message repeated 17 times: [ [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="error", 
    sender=":1.0" (uid=0 pid=833 comm="/lib/systemd/systemd-logind ") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="org.freedesktop.DBus
    .Error.UnknownMethod" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.147" (uid=1000 pid=4369 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell ")]`


so `org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod` is still the issue

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling gnome shell and wiping all configs with `sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell && sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`? You could also check your startup applications through another DE, but I doubt the cause would be there.

Comment: gnome wont launch  at all now lol, get ` /dev/sda1: clean` and a black screen, trying to troubleshoot through grub...

Comment: Perhaps gdm3 was removed somehow? Try installing it again from the GRUB command line