# Switch from Wayland back to Xorg on Dell Inspiron 5548

Tags: xorg, 17.10, wayland

**EDIT**: I installed Ubuntu 16.04 and updated to 17.10; Unity worked until update. Wayland takes place and is running well until now, except for what I forgot to mention, as follows.

Some [official info](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2018/01/26/bionic-beaver-18-04-lts-to-use-xorg-by-default/) tells Xorg will be the default graphic server for 18.04; Wayland stays as an second option. As I've experienced some GNOME Shell crashes, I realize the reason :)

Found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10) and executed its steps. At Login Screen, the cogwheel menu (⚙️) shows three options. First of them is "Ubuntu" for Wayland, which works. There are two other options: "Ubuntu on Xorg" don't work, and "Unity", which didn't work anymore.
I have executed @sam-thomas' answer, but Wayland didn't start. So I switched back to get Wayland work. That's why I think this is not a duplicate.

Got some app problems; Gparted didn't start, for example. I needed to use it and nothing appears on screen after password prompt, I could reproduce the case, for which the `xhost +SI:localuser:root` command gave temp solution, although I know it is not recommended.

I checked [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983606/unable-to-login-with-xorg-17-10-using-gnome-xorg-combo), but as my laptop is a Dell Inspiron 5548 with a AMD Radeon and Intel video cards, that shouldn't fit my case.

That said, what should I do to get Xorg working again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you switch from Wayland back to Xorg in Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10)

Comment: @N0rbert, I edited the question. Can you read it again? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized, after some search and time, that Xorg wasn't even installed on my laptop, possibly after upgrading to 17.10, when Wayland took place over after that.
That said, I managed to install Xorg using `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg --install-suggest`. Thus, both "Ubuntu on Xorg" and "Unity" options got to work, although Unity gets slow for some reason not yet identified.